How to prevent mouse event to freeze timers
I have a very simple macOS app that runs a NSTimer to update a value and display it on a NSTextField on my NSView.
The NSView also contains NSButton and NSSlider controls, not related to that timer.
When I hold mouse button on a NSButton or NSSlider, the timer does not update anymore, until I lift the mouse button (and then the timer resume).
How do I prevent the mouse button events to freeze timer?
The timer should not freeze when I hit and hold mouse button on the NSButton and NSSlider controls.
UPDATE:
I've found a solution, I need to subclass any NSButton and NSSlider objects, with empty mouse event functions like this:
  override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {}

(those functions are a lot).
Mouse event will not bother NSTimer anymore.
But this solution is tricky, I'll go for the suggested solution.

Is the timer not firing or the text field not updating? On which runloop do you schedule the timer? Post your code please.

Timer not firing at all while mouse button is down on any NSButton or NSSlider

It is a question of the run loop modes that you are using for the timer:

The “default” run loop modes will not let the timer fire while the user is interacting with the slider (or whatever). E.g., in Objective-C:
- (void)startUpdatingDefaultRunMode {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) {
            [timer invalidate];
            return;
        }
        strongSelf.label.stringValue = [strongSelf.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate now]];
    }];
}

Or Swift:
func startUpdatingDefaultRunMode() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self else { 
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        label.stringValue = dateFormatter.string(from: .now)
    }
}

Resulting in:


But if you use “common” run loop modes, the timer will continue to fire. In Objective-C:
- (void)startUpdatingCommonRunMode {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:0.02 repeats:true block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) {
            [timer invalidate];
            return;
        }
        strongSelf.label.stringValue = [strongSelf.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate now]];
    }];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

Or Swift:
func startUpdatingCommonRunMode() {
    let timer = Timer(fire: .now, interval: 0.02, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }
        label.stringValue = dateFormatter.string(from: .now)
    }
    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
}

Resulting in:



